# PIE encoding and SPI communication

Tags: microcontroller, spi

I am trying to understand the following situation:
I have an MCU (STM35L152RE), in which I am encoding digital data into PIE encoded data. Then I want to communicate this PIE encoded data with transceiver IC (S2LP) for modulation and transmit it over the air for the other receiver.
Is there any issue to communicate this PIE encoded data with transceiver IC via SPI communication? Will there be an issue with clock synchronization?

Comment: The devil's in the detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no issues.

Infact, PIE data will be the payload for S2LP.

S2LP will use its own bit and frame synchronization method.

S2LP won't use PIE synchronization method.

---

Clock synchronization is internally handled by S2LP.

Your microcontroller will receive an IRQ interrupt request from SL2P whenever a packet is ready.

---

You may program your S2LP to output its synchronization clock but that's useful only if you want your microcontroller to do data recovery and data synchronization.

I would leave your S2LP both clock and data recovery unless you want to test your own protocol.

Comment: I am actually planning to make a packet inside the MCU rather than using one from S2LP. Then the packet will be sent to S2LP for modulation and transmission over the air. I think there is a way to disable S2LP's frame and packet formation options completely along with encoding schemes.

Comment: Who is taking care of data and clock recovery? Your MCU or the S2LP?

Comment: My MCU. I am considering S2LP just as a transmitter and Receiver IC.

Comment: What if both MCU and S2LP are using the same clock for digital data handling? Will it help me in data and clock recovery better?

Comment: You will need to configure a GPIO pin of S2LP as CLOCK_OUT and another one as DATA_OUT. The bit slicer will be S2LP's responsability.

Comment: What do you mean by bit slicing? I do not know the meaning of it. 
On the other hand, a GPIO pin of S2LP as CLOCK_OUT shall be configured using a clock of S2LP? Then one also needs to do the same for GPIO DATA_IN operations?

Comment: Bit slicing is basically clock and bit recovery. That will be made by the S2LP transceiver. You will need STMicrolectronics' FAE help because I've never done that. I used the S2LP transceiver as black box that transmitted and received packets.